# WebElement' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep


url1 = input('[X] Введите ссылку на альбом : ')
browser.get(https://soundcloud.com/inside-edits/hamedit-posledniy-tanets-flip)
time.sleep(2)
cookies = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]")[0].click()
```

Не как не могу принять куки файлы,всё перепробывал ничего не помогает.
selenium=4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

У вас `find_element(...)[0].click()` а должно быть видимо `find_elements(...)[0].click()`.

Первый **уже** возвращает единичный элемент (поэтому обращаться к результату по индексу не имеет смысла), второй - несколько.

Comment: Заменил на cookies = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button[2]")[0].click()  Не помогло, 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable , До обновления селениума делал так browser.find_element_by_id('onetrust-accept-btn-handler').click() потом переписал под новую версию такая же ошибка.